# Comparar objetos en Java, sin solaparse

Tags: java

tengo un arraylist con objetos y quiero poder compararlos. Es un problema sobre solapamiento entre objetos.

[inicio-fin,inicio-fin,...]

> Mi arrayList de objetos: [5-6,7-8,1-4,8-12,3-8,6-12...]

Al recorrer este array compruebo si el inicio del primer objeto es mayor o igual que el del segundo objeto y si el final del primero es menor o igual que el del segundo. Pero no me lo realiza bien.

No sé que falla exactamente ¿es como recorro el arrayList? si es así ¿podéis ayudarme? o ¿es el método del solapamiento? ¿o ambos? Espero que podais ayudarme, gracias.

Deberían guardarse solo los objetos de la lista que no se solapen, pero no sé por qué falla si hay un objeto entre medias:

> Aquí [5-6,7-8,1-4,8-12,3-8,6-12...] se solapan 6-12 con 8-12, pero como está entre ellos 3-8, no los elimina. Y tampoco debería estar 3-8, por que se solapa con otro objeto.

Comment: Deberías plantearte ordenarlos primero. Por ejemplo, ordenarlos por el `item1` de la tupla y después poder comparar el `o1.item2 <= o2.item1`. De ese modo no tendrás nunca objetos intercalados, es decir, los objetos irán consecutivos.

Comment: @VRoxa El problema es que ya utilizo compareto en la clase objeto para ordenarlo de otra forma que necesito, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer dos compareTo en la clase objeto para si es necesario utilizar uno u otro? Si existe esa posibilidad, debería ponerse en la clase objeto? podría hacer en ambos métodos un if else para poder comparar?